# Issue with executing .exe written in C++ (using mingw compiler)

Tags: c++, gcc, build, mingw

I am new to programming and trying to learn C++ using C++ Primer (5th ed.). I have written this code that is directly from the book. The issue is when trying to execute the .exe results with this prompt popping up

> The procedure entry point _ZNKSt9basic_ioslcSt11char_traitslcEEcvbEv could not be located in the dll

The .cpp

```
#include <iostream>

main ()
{
    int sum = 0, val = 0;

    while (std::cin >> val) 
        sum += val;

    std::cout << "The sum is: " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not building it correctly or your compiler is misinstalled.

Comment: The problem is not in the C++ code you posted, but rather in the configuration of your compiler. I suggest you specify in your question which compiler you are using and set the appropriate tag in the question. For example, if you are using gcc, then tag it with "gcc".

Comment: As @AndreasWenzel wrote, you are likely either compiling a library instead of an .exe, or using an incorrect runtime, this has nothing to do with your code. If you're using an IDE, make sure you select a "console/dos application" when you create your project.

Comment: You've probably got a dll somewhere in your path which is being loaded instead of the runtime dll that your compiler is expecting

Comment: Does your book really not have an `int` return type for `main`?

Comment: @molbdnilo haha it does, that was just a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the directory where your mingw compiler is installed.
Within the "bin" directory you should finde several "*.dll" files like "libwinpthread-1.dll", "ligstdc++-6.dll" and so on...

These libraries are required to execute your application since mingw needs some platform wrapping magic (its a port of gcc for linux).

Try to copy these dll's into the same folder of where your "*.exe" is located.

If this does not help:
The error message is a bit confusing since I would expect it to report a dll file is missing instead of a missing procedure. In this case it looks like your compiler installation is broken or as already mentioned your build environment is not correctly set up. Which mingw version are you using, where did you get it from?

Comment: Copying the dll files into the compiling folder seemed to work. Im not exactly sure why the issue persisted with the dlls being in their initial location. I would have assumed following the environment setup from minGW website would have avoided an issue like this?